# NH QueryOver FetchMany Exception

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to query a parent User and then their `UserRoleMappings`. I have something similar to the below statement:

```
Dim userObj As User = session.Queryable(Of User)().Where(Function(x) x.username.Equals("someone")).FetchMany(Function(y) y.UserRoleMappings).SingleOrDefault()
```

When I try to run this statement I get the following exception:

> A fetch request must be a simple member access expression; 'Convert(y.UserRoleMappings)' is a UnaryExpression instead.
>   Parameter name: relatedObjectSelector

I can confirm that I got this to work in a C# Test Case, but unfortunately I need it to work in VB. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Could you possibly post your working C# code?

Comment: Here is the statement I am using in the c# test case:

CUser userObj = session.Queryable<User>().Where(o => o.username.Equals("someone")).FetchMany(y => y.UserRoleMappings).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: This is probably a problem with how they are converting the VB expression member... this is pretty common with libraries that don't test against VB.NET. The only way to fix it is to file a bug and hope they fix the offending code.

Comment: btw: This looks like Linq, not QueryOver. and I never saw session.Queryable<>, it;s usually session.Query<>

Comment: @PhilGood We ended up ditching this approach and going with Criteria.

Comment: I've created a new issue on NHibernate issues tracker.  https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2966